# How do I download SQL Server 2019 developer edition?

Tags: sql-server-2019

I've been looking around the web on how to download SQL serer 2019 Developer edition. Currently, on the Microsoft site they only have the 2022 version, so I was wondering how one can download older versions.
I stupidly did not get download the offline installer last time

Answer (score 24):

You can download it here:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866662

See also

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7201/sql-server-developer-edition-download-install-get-started/

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy, MS basically scrubbed the link from all their web pages. Please fix this MS, this is very annoying...

Comment: I am sure it is not something they want to 'fix'. They want you to use their latest.